# AttributeError: module 'aiobotocore' has no attribute 'AioSession' when reading csv from s3_path using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ubuntu, amazon-s3

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(<s3_path>)
```

I've tried running after uninstalling 'aiobotocore'.
I've tried this as well:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
pip install --upgrade aiobotocore
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/s3fs/core.py", line 378, in set_session
    self.session = aiobotocore.AioSession(**self.kwargs)
AttributeError: module 'aiobotocore' has no attribute 'AioSession'
```

How to resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am currently facing with this problem too.

Comment: still do you have it? facing it too :)